# WordPress autoload on database

Tags: database, wordpress

I am experiencing issues with my WordPress database, there are some plug-ins set to autoload that makes the database size exceed the recommended 800K for my host. Could the excessive database size cause other plug-ins and services not to work? How can I optimnize the database?

I have tried deactivating plug-ins and making sure the firewall isn't blocking site email notifications.

Comment: 800K for a database size limit is not nearly enough for a WordPress installation with anything more than a trivial number of posts. `autoload` refers to a setting on WordPress options. It's possible you activated one or more plugins that created an absurd number of autoloaded options. Try uninstalling plugins, not just deactivating them: they're supposed to delete options when you uninstall them. But many plugins don't.  Also, [edit] your question to tell us more and we may be better able to help you. Show us the exact error messages you get if you can.